# Load list view items

Tags: vb.net

I am making an application similar to AVA Find Pro (Pre caching files from my hard drive, then loading them in via a listview).

I am just wondering how AVA Find Pro loads all the items almost instantly. My application takes a while.

Is there a better/more efficient way than the standard way of using a listview?

thanks

Comment: You should post some code. The GUI is pretty quick to update changes, it's likely that your load time is being caused by something else.